# html5 webcam rtmp to server

Tags: html, nginx, live-streaming, wowza

i havel livestream php project ... isearched about webcam publisher to wowza and found this https://github.com/arut/nginx-rtmp-module/
but it have publish button i can not remove it as it build with action script 
and find that https://github.com/AF83/webcam-streaming 
but its video quality very bad 
and two have same problem that request flash allow at every starting stream 
now i want any webcam publisher built in html5  searched alot but all anserwer not completed ot i not able to understand

Comment: Kindly, this is a very poorly written question, can you please use period, comma and maybe paragraphs. I cannot get what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: It sounds like you are looking for webRTC, which allows you to access the client webcam via HTML5. If so, webRTC publisher streams are not yet supported in Wowza at this time.